# Help with looping through an XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml that looks like this

```
<words>
     <word>word1</word>
     <word>word2</word>
     <word>word3</word>
     <word>word4</word>
</words>
```

I would like to loop through the "word" tags and just output the innertext for now.
how would I do this?

here is what i am doing now but is says the list of nodes count is 1

```
        string _badWordFileDocPath = //my file path;
        XmlDocument badWordDoc = new XmlDocument();
        badWordDoc.Load(_badWordFileDocPath);


        XmlElement root = badWordDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/words");
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting the root `words` node itself, rather than the child `word` nodes.  Add `/word` to your XPath:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/words/word");
```

Comment: Thank you this was the quickest fix and worked perfectly. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You need to move down the node tree one more layer:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
 {
     XmlNodeList innerNodes = node.SelectNodes("/word");
     foreach(Xmlnode innerNode in innerNodes )
     {
          Console.WriteLine(innerNode.InnerText);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the classes in [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) for this task:

```
XElement wordsElement = XElement.Parse(yourXmlText);

var words = from w in wordsElement.Elements("word")
            select w.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you I may change to using linq as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing /word in your XPath.

You can also use Linq (XDocument) to fetch the data.